# How can I use a regex to convert street names in an address field to a standard format?

Tags: mysql, regex

I have the following list of street names that I need to rename:

```
N. SRª DE FÁTIMA
N. S. DE LOURDES
N. SRA. GUADALUPE
N. SRª DE FÁTIMA
N S PARECIDA
N SRA DA CONCEICAO
N.SRª.DE FÁTIMA
N. SRª.DE FÁTIMA
NS APARECIDA
NSRA DE FATIMA
NSA. SRA DE LOURDES
NSA SRA DA SAUDE
NSª DE FATIMA
N.S.FÁTIMA
```

I've tried to select match them with this pattern:

```
^N[SRAª]{0,3}[\.[:space:],]{1,3}[SRAª]{1,3}?[\.[:space:],]{1,3}
```

But `NSRA DE FATIMA`,`NSª DE FATIMA`, `NS APARECIDA` never show up in the query.
Basicly i want to replace those names like `N. SRª DE FÁTIMA` to `NOSSA SENHORA DE FÁTIMA`, but it musn't touch values like:

```
N. DESCOBERTA
N. ESPERANÇA
N.BETHANIA
NA ESTANCIA
```

I appreciate any help you could give me.

Comment: Please present the pattern you would like to match in a clear format. Your current description lacks several edge cases.

Comment: You need to describe the rules you want to implement. It's not enough to just show us some examples.

Comment: What version of MySQL?  (Regexp changed with 8.0)

Comment: A tip for saving your sanity:  Don't try to do it in a single regexp.

Answer (score 0):

You have to look at very name and see wh it doesn't fit.

this could work, but of course you could have false positives, of which we don't know about

For example NS APARECIDA   has no space after Aaparecida so it doesa appear with your old query, because it searches for dots space or comma.

> ```
> SELECT * FROM local WHERE nome RLIKE '^N[SRAª]{0,3}[\.[:space:],]{1,3}[SRAªDEB]{1,3}?[\.[:space:],]{0,3}'
> ```

> ```
> | nome                |
> | :------------------ |
> | N. SRª DE FÁTIMA  |
> | N. S. DE LOURDES    |
> | N. SRA. GUADALUPE   |
> | N. SRª DE FÁTIMA    |
> | N S PARECIDA        |
> | N SRA DA CONCEICAO  |
> | N.SRª.DE FÁTIMA     |
> | N. SRª.DE FÁTIMA    |
> | NS APARECIDA        |
> | NSRA DE FATIMA      |
> | NSA. SRA DE LOURDES |
> | NSA SRA DA SAUDE    |
> | NSª DE FATIMA       |
> | N.S.FÁTIMA          |
> | N. DESCOBERTA       |
> | N. ESPERANÇA        |
> | N.BETHANIA          |
> | NA ESTANCIA         |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=083c08abeadaf887e89d9b988d25f208)*